# How I can read all categories and subcategories in Firebase?

Tags: android, json, collections, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a lot of categories and subcategories in my app so I retrieved the date from firebase. after that, I try to convert this data to collections of the list to put in my GUI.
This is the example from my categories:
as you can see I have books category,
0--> attributes this category and 1--> is subcategories
I am so confused how I can read this categories and subcategories and put each category and subcategories in a list for I can use easily after that :).

[image: my categories]

Firebase ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default, null, false);
       ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : categoriesMap.entrySet()) {
               System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
           }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

           }
       });
```

}

the output of that code look like that:

```
Key = books,
   Value = [{name=books}, {cookbooks={name=CookBooks}, fiction={name=Fiction},
   accessories=[{name=Accessories}, {bookcovers={name=BookCovers},  otherbookaccessories={name=OtherBookAccessories}, bookmarks={name=BookMarks}, 
   booklights={name=BookLights}}], nonfiction={name=Nonfiction}, otherbooks=
    {name=OtherBooks}, agazine={name=Magazine}, catalogues={name=Catalogues}, 
    childreanyoungadult={name=ChildreanYoungAdult}, audiobooks={name=AudioBooks}, 
    textbookseducation={name=TextBooksEducation}, antiquariancollectible=
    {name=AntiquarianCollectible}}]
```

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to store?

Comment: I store  products in my categories but I need to get all the categories name from Firebase and show this name to a user.